# Trigger command from timeline

Tags: c#, wpf, timeline

I am trying to trigger a C# function/method from a frame in the timeline. How do I do that?

I don't know if it is possible, as I have searched Google and know how to control the timeline from the code, but I don't know if it is possible to do it the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle any animation's [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event.